# Searching database by tables linked with pivot using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to search my database for all `media` elements that have specific `attributes` and `tags`. The query is quite complicated, as it currently does the following:

- Search the `Media` table for a `Hash`, if it matches the regular expression for an MD5 hash.
- Search `Attributes` that are linked to the `Media`, and are called `Name`, `Description` and `Source`, using `WHERE LIKE`, and also doing `OR LIKE` on the each word in the search query, split up using the regular expression `/\s+/`.
- Search the `Tags`, checking the full search string in `Description` using `LIKE`, and then checking `Name` and `Slug` using the full search string and the individual words.

Currently I'm using a large piece of PHP which pieces the whole query together and then uses `DB::raw`, and doesn't really work properly. I've not included that since I felt it wasn't relevant since I wasn't using it correctly, but I'll include it if need be.

Is this actually possible using Laravel Eloquent or Fluent? Am I biting off more than I can realistically chew here?

Is this degree of search really necessary? Is there a better way of finding items with a certain title, description, source and tag(s)?

Thank you.

---

My `Media` table:

- ID
- Hash

My `Attributes` table:

- ID
- Name
- Value
- Media_ID

My `Tags` table:

- ID
- Name
- Slug
- Description

My `Tag_Media` table:

- Media_ID
- Tag_ID

Answer (score 0):

With your queries you join four tables and joins are the slowest SQL operation, if you can, you might want to merge all these tables in one bigger with all the columns already in place.
You'll waste memory with duplicates entry but usually that's ok to enhance querying performances.

A possible alternative of DB architecture with 2 tables (no duplicates):

My Media table:

- ID
- Hash
- Name
- Description
- Source

My Tags table:

- ID
- Name
- Slug
- Description
- Media_ID

A possible alternative of DB architecture with 1 table (for each media you need duplicate entries with same Media values and different tag values):

My Media table:

- ID
- Hash
- Name
- Description
- Source
- Tag_Name
- Tag_Slug
- Tag_Description

Also try indexing the columns you need to search over.
It's probably too heavy weaponry for this case but non relational DB might give you better performances.

Comment: Searches won't be that common in my application, so I figured that the current architecture was fine (besides, I already coded a lot of other stuff!). I don't mind overly if it takes a little while.